# How to convert string to django.db.models.query_utils.Q format?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-1.4

For a search function I want to save django query to database & later execute it. I have saved the query as shown below in one table(Company, which have id,qryText). The django query is saved as string.

```
qrySaved = (AND: ('code__in', ['10', '11', '12']), ('color__in', ['1', '2', '3']))
```

I am unable to execute it like

```
q = Company.objects.get(id=1)
Car.objects.filter(q.qryText)
```

as **q.qryText** is a string not **django.db.models.query_utils.Q** format.
How could I execute this string query ?

Comment: you can't do that!

Comment: ohh!!...is it..

Comment: You could convert it, of course. But what is `AND` in this case?

Comment: I am appending the query like this qrySaved = qrySaved & Q(**{"code__in" :['10', '11', '12']}). The list ['10', '11', '12'] is from request.POST

Comment: @Wolph pls let me know how to convert it

Comment: Is this a search history functionality? You could just store the lookup parameters in a dict and put that into the user's session for later use or store them as serialized json into the db. Serializing and deserializing a q object maybe goes much deeper that necessary? Can you provide more information about your use case?

Comment: It really depends on what you wish to do. If you're simply trying to store queries in the database for later re-use than I'd recommend storing them as json (or some other machine readable format).

As it is, the `qrySaved = ...` line is not valid Python since `AND` is not defined so unless you add some additional information I can't help you.

Comment: @trixn I want to store the queries into the db..there is a lot of parameters in this search,so the user wants to save a search & execute it whenever needed

Comment: @Wolph  I want to store the queries into the db.. The **AND** is getting whenever I print **qrySaved**.  where  **qrySaved = qrySaved & Q(**{"code__in" :['10', '11', '12']})**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string representation of the query is not easily (safely) reversible so I would try a different type of encoding instead. For example, using the pickle library instead.

To encode:

```
import pickle
from django.db.models import query_utils

q = Q(code__in=[10, 11, 12], color_in=[1, 2, 3])
q_pickled = pickle.dumps(q)
```

To decode again:

```
# Assuming that q_pickled is available and is a valid pickled string
import pickle

q = pickle.loads(q_pickled)
```

Comment: okay..i've pickled the query & saved to db, then unpickle & execute it whenever needed... is it a good method to save pickled to db ?

Comment: It's definitely the easiest method in this case but there are security risks involved. The pickle system allows you to pickle just about anything so if someone can modify the pickles and call them after they can execute code on your system. Although that's a right that only admins should have normally so it might not matter in your case. Additionally (which goes for just about any version of this), there's also a risk in executing queries which come from the user since they can execute a DOS attack.